# Gradle failures following update of android studio to version 3.4

Tags: android-studio, gradle, flutter

I've updated Android studio today and my flutter project is no longer working.  Gradle is failing with the following message:

---

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Projects\firebase_setup_app\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

> Configure project :app
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
WARNING: API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getJavaCompile(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getMergeAssets(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
         *********************************************************
WARNING: This version of firebase_auth will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
         See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
         This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
         *********************************************************
  Command: C:\Projects\firebase_setup_app\android\gradlew.bat app:properties
Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

---

I've tried making a new flutter project in the latest version of studio and this builds OK.

The issue seems to be around the fact I'm using google play services and  firebase in my project.  I updated google services to the latest (4.2.0) and gradle to 3.4.0 following a prompt from the IDE

I updated the compiledSDKVersion from 27 to 28 in android/app/build.gradle

I've updated the gradle version in android/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties from 4.10.2 to 5.1.1 as there was an incompatibility and I was prompted to update.

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

I've done the refactor>migrate to AndroidX... and included:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in the gradle.properties file

I've tried clearing the cache via 'File>Invalidate Caches and restart...'

I have tried flutter clean and flutter doctor -v with no issues shown:

```
C:\Projects\firebase_setup_app>flutter clean
Deleting 'build\'.
Deleting 'C:\Projects\firebase_setup_app\.dart_tool\'.

C:\Projects\firebase_setup_app>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600], locale en-GB)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.3)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!

C:\Projects\firebase_setup_app>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600], locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.2.1 at C:\src\flutter\flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable\flutter
    • Framework revision 8661d8aecd (10 weeks ago), 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
    • Engine revision 3757390fa4
    • Dart version 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin version 34.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 183.5901
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.3)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.3
    • Flutter plugin version 31.3.4
    • Dart plugin version 183.5153.38

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM G930F • ce0616069dbace2f03 • android-arm64 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26)

• No issues found!
```

---

I've also updated the android/build.gradle dependencies:

```
   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
```

The android/app/build.gradle dependencies are as follows:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

my pubspec.yaml includes the following plugins:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+3
  firebase_auth: ^0.8.4+5
  firebase_core: ^0.3.4
  #firebase_core: any
  firebase_database: ^2.0.3
```

Any suggestions please to resolve greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is with `androidX`[as I have seen in the error] and also for the fact that you are using `firebase_auth: ^0.8.4+5`.

1.use the latest version of android studio

2. open your flutter project in android studio, go to Refactor,select Migrate to androidX.
3. when prompted to with a window open the window in a new tab[open in a new android studio window], this will open your android app folder in this window select migrate to android X again.
   when the process is done navigate to the bottom and select refactor.
   lunch your app again

hope this helps
check this out: https://medium.com/@swhussain110/how-to-migrate-your-flutter-app-to-androidx-9a78eaaa924b

Comment: Thanks, I tried this originally but have tried again following your answer. Following I get a popup with the message "No Usages Found in the project" and it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: I've just worked through the medium artical and done the flutter>open module in android studio>new window part.  The build seems to fail due to an incompatibility with the Kotlin plugin as I get the following message:  ERROR: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
root project 'android' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71
Affected Modules: app

Comment: Have done the refactor and upgraded Kotlin 1.3.30 via Tools>Kotlin>Configure Kotlin Updates and updated gradle.build ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.30' and now the build give the following message: Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: I then found my google-services.json was not at the app level.  Moving this allowed me to refactor and migrate to androidX.  All issues now fixed!!!! Thanks so much for the help, the guy in the artical struggled for 10 days so I'm glad I asked!!!  Cheers.